# How can I optimize this simple join query? It takes a long time

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, join

I am not sure on how to begin optimizing this High Latency SQL query that my platform runs. Other than reducing the datasets, what are some things that I can do?

```
SELECT ctm.* 
FROM compound_transaction_map ctm 
JOIN bustransaction_map btm ON ctm.transId = btm.transId 
WHERE btm.docId = ?
```

**docId** gets inserted by my DBWConnector in the Java code

The main issue the size of the tables, compound_transaction_map is **776,387** entries and bustransaction_map is **3,252,772**. I am working on reducing the table sizes, but just wondering if this query is also an issue.

Just looking to get some insight from someone more experienced than me. I appreciate your help.

**Edit:** There are indexes on transId and bustransaction_map.docID

```
mysql> show index from compound_transaction_map;
+--------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                    | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| compound_transaction_map |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |      765804 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| compound_transaction_map |          0 | UNQ_compoundId_transId |            1 | transId     | A         |      772560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| compound_transaction_map |          0 | UNQ_compoundId_transId |            2 | compoundId  | A         |      772560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| compound_transaction_map |          1 | transId                |            1 | transId     | A         |      772560 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| compound_transaction_map |          1 | compoundId             |            1 | compoundId  | A         |      645871 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| compound_transaction_map |          1 | companyId              |            1 | companyId   | A         |         625 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

```
mysql> show index from bustransaction_map;
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| bustransaction_map |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     2869993 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bustransaction_map |          0 | docId    |            1 | docId       | A         |     2883521 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| bustransaction_map |          1 | transId  |            1 | transId     | A         |     1019639 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT ctm.*
IN bustransaction_ma    -> FROM compound_transaction_map ctm
    -> JOIN bustransaction_map btm ON ctm.transId = btm.transId
    -> WHERE btm.docId = '62EFCD90-BC62-9984-0B20-4465528D6359';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | btm   | NULL       | const | docId,transId | docId | 153     | const |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ctm   | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | 772560 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE compound_transaction_map;
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                    | Create Table

                                                            |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| compound_transaction_map | CREATE TABLE `compound_transaction_map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compoundId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `transId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `companyId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_compoundId_transId` (`transId`,`compoundId`),
  KEY `transId` (`transId`),
  KEY `compoundId` (`compoundId`),
  KEY `companyId` (`companyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=865326 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE bustransaction_map;
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table              | Create Table
                                                                                                                |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| bustransaction_map | CREATE TABLE `bustransaction_map` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `docId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `docId` (`docId`),
  KEY `transId` (`transId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13033253 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select ctm.* from bustransaction_map btm join compound_transaction_map ctm force index (transId) on ctm.transId = btm.transId where btm.docId = '62EFCD90-BC62-9984-0B20-4465528D6359';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | btm   | NULL       | const | docId,transId | docId | 153     | const |      1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ctm   | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | 772560 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This may be useful for `btm`:  `INDEX(docId, transId)`

Comment: @RickJames where would I add this `btm: INDEX(docId, transId)` to the query?

Comment: @RickJames they are looking up a single unique key docId, so seems like any improvement will need to come in ctm.

Comment: not sure why it is reading all of ctm when you have appropriate indexes.  maybe because of the size mismatch?  can you make both transId's 50 or both 100 chars?

Comment: select * in general is bad practice, better to explicitly list the columns you need (not going to give a performance improvement though)

Comment: @ysth Yeah `select *` is bad and will change that when I get to it for good coding practices' sake. But yes, unfortunately not going to give performance.

Not sure either why it is reading all of ctm. I just noticed that transId's are not the same. I could make them both 100 chars. Would that make a difference performance wise?

Comment: if making the lengths match doesn't help, next step is trying an index hint `select ctm.* from bustransaction_map btm join compound_transaction_map ctm force index (transId) on ctm.transId = btm.transId where btm.docId = ?` and seeing if the explain changes

Comment: I just added that

Comment: yes, changing both to 100 (or both to 36 if these are all uuids) should make it willing to use an index on ctm

Answer (score 2):

1. Be consistent on character sets.  `ON ctm.transId = btm.transId` is failing to use an obvious index because of the inconsistency; this is leading to a terrible table scan in the second table in `EXPLAIN`.
2. If `bustransaction_map` is a "many-to-many mapping" table, get rid of `id` and have

   ```
    PRIMARY KEY(docId, transId),
    INDEX(transId, docId)
   ```
3. Let's see other uses of the other table; they may need changes like in item 2.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can only use one index per table. The `explain` shows that it chose to use the index on `bustransaction_map.docId` to help with the `where docId = ?`; bustransaction_map is the larger table so it wants to cut down its rows. It uses no index on `compound_transaction_map`.

To solve this, [create a compound index](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_index.asp) on bustransaction_map of `(docId, transId)` (the order is important). MySQL can use this index for any queries which feature just `bustransaction_map.docId` and queries which use both `bustransaction_map.docId` and `bustransaction_map.transId` like yours.

You can then drop the index on `docId`, it's redundant. You can also drop the  single column index on `compound_transaction_map.transId`, it is redundant with the compound index on `(transId, compoundId)`.

---

In general, if you have two columns you can cover all queries containing any combination of them with two indexes...

- A
- (B, A)

---

More notes:

- Only restrict varchar sizes if the data has an inherent size limit, otherwise use `varchar(255)`. "varchar" means "variable [size] characters"; MySQL will only use as much space as it needs. Arbitrary restrictions just cause future headaches.
- Your transId is of different sizes in each table: one is varchar(50) and one is varchar(100). If they're referring to the same thing they should be the same.

Comment: don't believe this will help.  docId in bustransaction_map is a unique key, so the docId = ? is going to find just one row (if any), and the covering index will save it looking up just that one full docId record.

Comment: Thank you for that response. I appreciate your help a lot and this gives me somewhere to start learning and improving.

Comment: @ysth so would there be no need to do this?

Comment: @Helpfusali First try making the types on transid are the same, that may be why it's not using the compound_transaction_map.transId index. If transId refers to a key in another table, you should declare it as a [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_foreignkey.asp). If that doesn't work, try the compound index. ysth may be right, but there's no cost to trying. [It won't lock the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-index-syntax-notes). You can drop the index if it doesn't work.

Comment: adding an index?  I don't think it would help at all.  getting it using an index on the other table is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT ctm.* 
FROM compound_transaction_map ctm 
WHERE ctm.transid in
    (select btm.transid 
     from bustransaction_map btm 
     WHERE btm.docId = ?
    )
```

I think, for subquery will be used index (docId) - index seek, or (docId,transId) - only index scan.
For join will be used `range join` with index on ctm.transId.